# Multiplicar por el resultado booleano de un numero

Tags: php

Tengo las horas trabajadas por un trabajador y el salario diario. Tal que:

```
$horas = 8;
$precio = 88;

$pagar = 0;
if($horas > 0){
    $pagar = $precio
}

return $pagar.
```

Trabaje lo que trabaje, a menos que `$horas` sean 0, yo le voy a pagar el día. Entonces me gustaría ahorrarme el if (en el código real es todo mas complejo aunque en el ejemplo parezca simple). Tengo esto:

```
$pagar = $precio * ($horas/$horas);
```

Claro esto es que si `$horas` es 8 y dividido entre si mismo es 1, y puedo multiplicarlo bien. El caso es que si `$horas` es 0, dividir entre no es del todo correcto.

Y aquí la pregunta del titulo, puedo multiplicar directamente por el resultado booleano del numero? es decir, algo como:

```
$precio * intval(boolval($horas));
```

este caso funciona, pero no en `PHP 5.4`, ya que `boolval` es para `PHP 5.5+` y también creo que debe ser mas simple que llamar a 2 funciones

Gracias

Comment: pero... en tu ejemplo les pagas a todos como si hubieran trabajado una sola hora ¿Qué sentido tiene eso?

Comment: Yo tengo que al dia pago 100£, si trabajas 1h te voy a pagar 100 £, si trabajas 23h te voy a pagar 100£. Si has trabajado te voy  pagar lo que ponga en el precio independientemente de cuanto. 
Ademas, es el sentido que tienen las especificaciones de la aplicacion. Soy programador, no de recursos humanos

Comment: Comprendo que el ejemplo que pones es simplificado, pero en el caso real más complejo, ¿sería posible hacerlo con un operador ternario simple? Algo como `$pagar = $horas ? $precio : 0;` donde $horas evaluará a true siempre que sea diferente de 0 (asumiendo que no se puede trabajar un número negativo).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Genial, me sirve. Estaba muy encabezonado buscando alguna multiplicacion y realmente es una simple asignacion. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías plantearte usar un operador ternario (o Elvis) para asignar el valor directamente a partir del número de horas. Sería algo bastante simple:

```
$pagar = $horas ? $precio : 0;
```

La idea es que los números evalúan a `true` siempre que no sean cero. (Asumiendo que no vas a tener un número negativo de horas, lo cual no tendría mucho sentido). Entonces si `$horas` no es cero, `$pagar` recibe el valor `$precio`, de lo contrario recibe le valor 0.

Answer (score 2):

Qué tal algo así?

```
function pagar ($horas) {
    $precio = 88;
    return ($horas ? $precio : 0);
}
```

[Aquí tienes una demo](https://www.ideone.com/IOhkRN).